# If there is only one UI thread, how can several event handlers be active at the same time?

Tags: .net, winforms, thread-safety

I've noticed that if I modify the `.Text` property of a control (e.g. `FirstName.Text = "foo";`) while in another control's event (e.g. `LastName_TextChanged`), the other control's event handler (e.g. `FirstName_TextChanged`) seems to execute immediately, interrupting the execution of `LastName_TextChanged`, which then resumes.

How does this square with the concept of a "single UI thread".  Why don't all events execute in sequence (serially)?

Comment: The event handler is likely directly called when accessing the property. So in the setter of the property it will raise the event, and call and runt the event handler. I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: When you set `FirstName.Text = "something"`, you have already caused the execution of other code. The setter calls `OnTextChanged()`, which *raises the event*, calling the registered handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is "reentrancy", which is similar to but importantly different from "concurrency".

Specifically, all of the code is still executing in a single thread. But events are raised as they happen, whether or not handling of a given event has completed. Something like this:

```cs
public event EventHandler TextChanged

private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get => _text;
    set
    {
        _text = value;
        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

(The above is for illustration purposes only; it's not literally how the events are actually implemented, but it does have the same semantics.)

When a handler is subscribed to the `TextChanged` event, that handler is invoked *as part of* the property setter. This means the event is raised before the assignment to the property returns to the caller.

If you have two different objects, and a handler that sets the `Text` property of one object when handling the `TextChanged` event of the other, then the assignment of that first object's `Text` property is necessarily going to happen before the handler returns (since it's happening *as part of* that handler's operation), raising that first object's `TextChanged` event, and the second object's setter can't return until the handler for the second object's `TextChanged` event returns.

You wind up with execution of both handlers in progress at the same time, because effectively the first event handler *called* the second event handler. It did so indirectly, through delegates subscribed to the events, but it is still essentially a nested method call. It's really not much different from this:

```
void M1()
{
    M2();
}

void M2()
{
    // M1 hasn't returned yet, and yet here we are in M2!
}
```

I.e. we don't ask why it's possible for both `M1()` and `M2()` to be called at the same time in the same thread. You can have any number of methods in the progress of executing in a given thread, in the sense that each method hasn't returned.

The important thing to keep in mind is that the thread's instruction pointer — the thing that says exactly which program statement is currently executing — can only be in on method at a time. While `M1()` is technically still executing in the sense that it hasn't returned yet, it's not really executing *concurrently* with `M2()`. The execution of `M1()` is put on hold until `M2()` returns.

And likewise, in your event handlers, the two handlers aren't really executing at the same time. Execution of the first handler invoked is put on hold while the property it's setting is having its setter called, and this means it's also on hold while the second handler invoked is executing (because the property setter won't return until that handler is invoked and then returns).

Comment: So it seems that events triggered from code are handled differently than those triggered by the user.  The ones from code are called immediately, while the ones from the user are added to a queue, to be called in the event loop?

Comment: It depends on how the events triggered from code are actually triggered. All of the .NET GUI platforms provide a mechanism to enqueue actions on the thread's event loop, and of course one could take advantage of that mechanism to delay invocation of events. But in general, yes...if one is simply executing code that in turns raises events directly, this is a completely different mechanism from the kinds of events that result from user interaction, the latter involving e.g. window messages queued to the thread's message queue for later dispatch to the window proc.